# PowerShell to get count of employees working in every hour of the day

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV of basically a time sheet of IN and Out times. This is a sample.

```
"Employee Id","Work Date","In","Out"
"1011","01/16/2023","1/16/23 11:04 PM","1/17/23 6:52 AM"
"1012","01/16/2023","1/16/23 11:18 PM","1/17/23 6:05 AM"
"1012","01/17/2023","1/17/23 10:49 PM","1/18/23 7:26 AM"
"1021","01/16/2023","1/16/23 11:18 PM","1/17/23 6:04 AM"
"1021","01/17/2023","1/17/23 10:46 PM","1/18/23 8:12 AM"
"10261","01/16/2023","1/16/23 6:02 AM","1/16/23 12:01 PM"
```

I've created the intended output file, but I'm stuck on how to get a count of people for each hour. Here is the output creation.

```
$data = 0..23 | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        WorkDate = "1/17/2023"
        Hour     =  $_
        Count = 0
    }
}
$data
```

This is the blank Output.

```
"WorkDate","Hour","Count"
"1/17/2023","0","0"
"1/17/2023","1","0"
"1/17/2023","2","0"
"1/17/2023","3","0"
"1/17/2023","4","0"
"1/17/2023","5","0"
"1/17/2023","6","0"
"1/17/2023","7","0"
"1/17/2023","8","0"
"1/17/2023","9","0"
"1/17/2023","10","0"
"1/17/2023","11","0"
"1/17/2023","12","0"
"1/17/2023","13","0"
"1/17/2023","14","0"
"1/17/2023","15","0"
"1/17/2023","16","0"
"1/17/2023","17","0"
"1/17/2023","18","0"
"1/17/2023","19","0"
"1/17/2023","20","0"
"1/17/2023","21","0"
"1/17/2023","22","0"
"1/17/2023","23","0"
```

I know the basics of what I need to do, but new to powershell so struggling to put it all together. I need to loop through the output and create a datetime of Workdate+Hour (ie 1/17/2023 0:00) and loop through the data to check if that is >= In and <= Out, then iterated a variable and update the count. Then move to the next hour.

This would be the output give my current input example. For example 1012 has 2 entries in the dataset. The first would be counted for hours 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 on 1/17. Same for 1011, and 1012, but 10261 didn't work at all 1/17.

```
WorkDate,Hour,Count
1/17/2023,0,3
1/17/2023,1,3
1/17/2023,2,3
1/17/2023,3,3
1/17/2023,4,3
1/17/2023,5,3
1/17/2023,6,3
1/17/2023,7,0
1/17/2023,8,0
1/17/2023,9,0
1/17/2023,10,0
1/17/2023,11,0
1/17/2023,12,0
1/17/2023,13,0
1/17/2023,14,0
1/17/2023,15,0
1/17/2023,16,0
1/17/2023,17,0
1/17/2023,18,0
1/17/2023,19,0
1/17/2023,20,0
1/17/2023,21,0
1/17/2023,22,0
1/17/2023,23,0
```

Comment: Just to rephrase so I can understand a bit better. So, you're looking to count the total amount of users that worked each hour based on their `In` date? Will there ever be duplicates in your csv, such as, a user may have came back or something like that? Do you mind updating your post to show what an expected result should look like based on your example csv?

Comment: yes they could be multiple entries for each employee but none would overlap. and it would be based on both their IN and OUT times because they could start before midnight on 1/17 but need to be counted for the morning hours that run into 1/17. I've added what the output should be, it stripped the "" but thats not a biggie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work :

```
$data = @"
"Employee Id","Work Date","In","Out"
"1011","01/16/2023","1/16/23 11:04 PM","1/17/23 6:52 AM"
"1012","01/16/2023","1/16/23 11:18 PM","1/17/23 6:05 AM"
"1012","01/17/2023","1/17/23 10:49 PM","1/18/23 7:26 AM"
"1021","01/16/2023","1/16/23 11:18 PM","1/17/23 6:04 AM"
"1021","01/17/2023","1/17/23 10:46 PM","1/18/23 8:12 AM"
"10261","01/16/2023","1/16/23 6:02 AM","1/16/23 12:01 PM"
"@

$table = $data | ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach($row in $table)
{
   $startDate = ([System.DateTime]::ParseExact($row.In,"M/d/yy h:mm tt",$null))
   #for count to work properly you need to truncate minutes
   $startDate = $startDate.AddMinutes(-$startDate.Minute)
   $row | Add-Member -NotePropertyName InDate -NotePropertyValue $startDate
   $row | Add-Member -NotePropertyName OutDate -NotePropertyValue ([System.DateTime]::ParseExact($row.Out,"M/d/yy h:mm tt",$null))
}


$table | Format-Table
$minDate = $table | Measure-Object -Property InDate -Minimum
Write-Host $minDate.Minimum
$maxDate = $table | Measure-Object -Property OutDate -Maximum
Write-Host $maxDate.Maximum
#subtract minutes to get hour
$minDate = $minDate.minimum.AddMinutes(-$minDate.minimum.Minute)
$maxDate = $maxDate.maximum.AddMinutes(-$maxDate.maximum.Minute)
Write-Host "min date = " $minDate "max date = " $maxDate

$out_table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
for($date = $minDate; $date -le $maxDate; $date = $date.AddHours(1))
{
   $table | foreach {Write-Host "in = " $_.InDate "out = " $_.OutDate "date = " $date "start = " ($_.InDate -le $date) "end = " ($_.OutDate -ge $date) }
   $numEmployees = @($table | Where-Object { ($_.InDate -le $date) -and ($_.OutDate -ge $date)})
Write-Host "count = " $numEmployees.Count "employees = " $numEmployees
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Hour -NotePropertyValue $date

   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Count -NotePropertyValue $numEmployees.Count
   $out_table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}
$out_table | Format-Table
```

Results

```
Hour                  Count
----                  -----
1/16/2023 6:00:00 AM      1
1/16/2023 7:00:00 AM      1
1/16/2023 8:00:00 AM      1
1/16/2023 9:00:00 AM      1
1/16/2023 10:00:00 AM     1
1/16/2023 11:00:00 AM     1
1/16/2023 12:00:00 PM     1
1/16/2023 1:00:00 PM      0
1/16/2023 2:00:00 PM      0
1/16/2023 3:00:00 PM      0
1/16/2023 4:00:00 PM      0
1/16/2023 5:00:00 PM      0
1/16/2023 6:00:00 PM      0
1/16/2023 7:00:00 PM      0
1/16/2023 8:00:00 PM      0
1/16/2023 9:00:00 PM      0
1/16/2023 10:00:00 PM     0
1/16/2023 11:00:00 PM     3
1/17/2023 12:00:00 AM     3
1/17/2023 1:00:00 AM      3
1/17/2023 2:00:00 AM      3
1/17/2023 3:00:00 AM      3
1/17/2023 4:00:00 AM      3
1/17/2023 5:00:00 AM      3
1/17/2023 6:00:00 AM      3
1/17/2023 7:00:00 AM      0
1/17/2023 8:00:00 AM      0
1/17/2023 9:00:00 AM      0
1/17/2023 10:00:00 AM     0
1/17/2023 11:00:00 AM     0
1/17/2023 12:00:00 PM     0
1/17/2023 1:00:00 PM      0
1/17/2023 2:00:00 PM      0
1/17/2023 3:00:00 PM      0
1/17/2023 4:00:00 PM      0
1/17/2023 5:00:00 PM      0
1/17/2023 6:00:00 PM      0
1/17/2023 7:00:00 PM      0
1/17/2023 8:00:00 PM      0
1/17/2023 9:00:00 PM      0
1/17/2023 10:00:00 PM     2
1/17/2023 11:00:00 PM     2
1/18/2023 12:00:00 AM     2
1/18/2023 1:00:00 AM      2
1/18/2023 2:00:00 AM      2
1/18/2023 3:00:00 AM      2
1/18/2023 4:00:00 AM      2
1/18/2023 5:00:00 AM      2
1/18/2023 6:00:00 AM      2
1/18/2023 7:00:00 AM      2
1/18/2023 8:00:00 AM      1
```

Comment: That did the trick, I  like this one best since I no longer need to specify a date. It just counts all available in any given dataset.

Comment: I updated.  Found a few issues.

Comment: I couldn't sleep.  It bothered me that the first row and last row of results should contain at least one employee.  Went back and discovered that Where-Object when only returns only one item the results is not an array so Count returns null.  The solution is to force and array by putting `@()` around the statement.  Also when employee start at 6:02 AM the hour gives zero so I had to make the start time 6:00 by subtracting the number of minutes.  Code is now working and I can go to sleep.

Comment: @BradHieb, so does the other answer (it originally explicitly narrowed the results to a specific date only, because that is a requirement implied by your question) - and it does so much more efficiently, by avoiding `Add-Member` calls, which are quite expensive, and by avoiding repeatedly looping over the input rows for _each and every hour_.

Comment: @mklement0 : You are looping three times through tables (not including debug code) and I'm only looping twice.  I'm only converting the strings to DateTime once and you are doing the conversion every time through the loop.  The Add-Member is saving doing a conversion to DateTime every loop.

Comment: @jdweng, your code has many implicit loops over the data, using `Measure-Object` and `Where-Object`. While those are faster than looping in PowerShell code,
it still adds up - see benchmarks below.

Comment: @BradHieb, you should definitely accept what answer you're comfortable with, I was just pointing out that your stated rationale for preferring this answer was not correct.
It isn't necessarily the accepted answer that proves to be most popular in the long run. As for performance, see the next comment.

Comment: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/e8cabb620342af37ae7d0faecba7d588#file-bm_75174855-ps1) for benchmarks. With 1,000 sample data rows averaged over
15 runs, this answer is about 10 times slower than the other one in Windows PowerShell and - curiously - only 5 times slower in PowerShell (Core) 7.3.1 on Windows 11.
On macOS with 7.3.1, the factor is again about 10.

Comment: @mklement0 : I have a lot of test code so OP can see properties.  Did you run mu code with just raw code with no test outputs?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a self-contained example using in-memory CSV in- and output ([`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv) and [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv)); in your real code, use the file-based equivalents ([`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) and [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)):

```bash
# Initialize an ordered hashtable whose entries will
# map calendar days to arrays with 24 elements each representing
# an hour of the day, with the element values containing the 
# count of clocked-in employees for the given hour.
$hourMap = [ordered] @{}

@'
"Employee Id","Work Date","In","Out"
"1011","01/16/2023","1/16/23 11:04 PM","1/17/23 6:52 AM"
"1012","01/16/2023","1/16/23 11:18 PM","1/17/23 6:05 AM"
"1012","01/17/2023","1/17/23 10:49 PM","1/18/23 7:26 AM"
"1021","01/16/2023","1/16/23 11:18 PM","1/17/23 6:04 AM"
"1021","01/17/2023","1/17/23 10:46 PM","1/18/23 8:12 AM"
"10261","01/16/2023","1/16/23 6:02 AM","1/16/23 12:01 PM"
'@ | 
ConvertFrom-Csv |
ForEach-Object {
  # Get the in an out timestamps as [datetime] instances, 
  # reset to the start of the hour.
  $in, $out =
    ($_.In, $_.Out).ForEach({ Get-Date $_ -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Millisecond 0 })
  # Loop over all hours in the time between in and out.
  $timestamp = $in
  while ($timestamp -le $out) {
    # For the timestamp's calendar day, create a 24-element array 
    # representing the hours of the day; a given element's value will
    # receive the count of clocked-in employees for that hour.
    if (-not $hourMap.Contains($timestamp.Date)) {
      $hourMap[$timestamp.Date] = [int[]]::new(24)
    }
    $hourMap[$timestamp.Date][$timestamp.Hour]++
    $timestamp = $timestamp.AddHours(1)
  }
}

# Create the output objects for a given calendar day
# and convert them to CSV.
$workDate = '1/17/2023'
$hoursToCounts = $hourMap[[datetime] $workDate]
0..23 |
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      WorkDate = $workDate
      Hour     = $_
      Count    = $hoursToCounts[$_]
    }
  } |
  ConvertTo-Csv
```

Output:

```bash
"WorkDate","Hour","Count"
"1/17/2023","0","3"
"1/17/2023","1","3"
"1/17/2023","2","3"
"1/17/2023","3","3"
"1/17/2023","4","3"
"1/17/2023","5","3"
"1/17/2023","6","3"
"1/17/2023","7","0"
"1/17/2023","8","0"
"1/17/2023","9","0"
"1/17/2023","10","0"
"1/17/2023","11","0"
"1/17/2023","12","0"
"1/17/2023","13","0"
"1/17/2023","14","0"
"1/17/2023","15","0"
"1/17/2023","16","0"
"1/17/2023","17","0"
"1/17/2023","18","0"
"1/17/2023","19","0"
"1/17/2023","20","0"
"1/17/2023","21","0"
"1/17/2023","22","2"
"1/17/2023","23","2"
```

---

Note: The above - as requested in your question - limits the output to a *specific, given date*. However, the solution provides results across *all* dates, and if you want **to list *all* results, across *all* dates**, simply replace the last paragraph with the following:

```bash
# Loop over all $hourMap entries, each representing a calendar day
$hourMap.GetEnumerator() |  
  ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($hour in 0..23) { # For each calendar day, loop over all hours.
      [pscustomobject] @{
        WorkDate = $_.Key.ToString('d')
        Hour     = $hour
        Count    = $_.Value[$hour]
      }
    }
  } |
  ConvertTo-Csv
```

Output:

```bash
"WorkDate","Hour","Count"
"1/16/2023","0","0"
"1/16/2023","1","0"
"1/16/2023","2","0"
"1/16/2023","3","0"
"1/16/2023","4","0"
"1/16/2023","5","0"
"1/16/2023","6","1"
"1/16/2023","7","1"
"1/16/2023","8","1"
"1/16/2023","9","1"
"1/16/2023","10","1"
"1/16/2023","11","1"
"1/16/2023","12","1"
"1/16/2023","13","0"
"1/16/2023","14","0"
"1/16/2023","15","0"
"1/16/2023","16","0"
"1/16/2023","17","0"
"1/16/2023","18","0"
"1/16/2023","19","0"
"1/16/2023","20","0"
"1/16/2023","21","0"
"1/16/2023","22","0"
"1/16/2023","23","3"
"1/17/2023","0","3"
"1/17/2023","1","3"
"1/17/2023","2","3"
"1/17/2023","3","3"
"1/17/2023","4","3"
"1/17/2023","5","3"
"1/17/2023","6","3"
"1/17/2023","7","0"
"1/17/2023","8","0"
"1/17/2023","9","0"
"1/17/2023","10","0"
"1/17/2023","11","0"
"1/17/2023","12","0"
"1/17/2023","13","0"
"1/17/2023","14","0"
"1/17/2023","15","0"
"1/17/2023","16","0"
"1/17/2023","17","0"
"1/17/2023","18","0"
"1/17/2023","19","0"
"1/17/2023","20","0"
"1/17/2023","21","0"
"1/17/2023","22","2"
"1/17/2023","23","2"
"1/18/2023","0","2"
"1/18/2023","1","2"
"1/18/2023","2","2"
"1/18/2023","3","2"
"1/18/2023","4","2"
"1/18/2023","5","2"
"1/18/2023","6","2"
"1/18/2023","7","2"
"1/18/2023","8","1"
"1/18/2023","9","0"
"1/18/2023","10","0"
"1/18/2023","11","0"
"1/18/2023","12","0"
"1/18/2023","13","0"
"1/18/2023","14","0"
"1/18/2023","15","0"
"1/18/2023","16","0"
"1/18/2023","17","0"
"1/18/2023","18","0"
"1/18/2023","19","0"
"1/18/2023","20","0"
"1/18/2023","21","0"
"1/18/2023","22","0"
"1/18/2023","23","0"
```